# how perform IBAction declared in separate cell class from collection view controller

Tags: ios, swift, ibaction

I create `UIButton` in the collection view cell, and set the appearance state to hidden.
Also I declared `@IBAction` to delete items from collection view

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

  @IBAction func deleteButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    // deletion code
  }
```

in the collection view, I've navigation bar button, which cause that the delete button appears. 
How to perform the the `deleteButtonTapped` action that was previously declared in cell class, after I tap the delete button.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect your delete button to the delete action in your collection view cell subclass from the storyboard. You can also do it programmatically by first creating an outlet in your subclass and associating your delete action to your button.

```
@IBOutlet weak var deleteButton: UIButton! {
  didSet {
    deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
  }
}
```